# Everything stops working after add opacity (in Tailwind)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

This is my HTML document. Everything looks good after adding an `opacity-50` class for my `img` tag (I tried to add opacity to other tags and even make my header my `img` tag sibling but still the problem exists):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fonts/fontawesome-free-6.4.2-web/css/all.css">

    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Ubunto";
            src: url("./fonts/Ubuntu-Medium.ttf");
        }

        .fo-color {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <header class="overflow-hidden text-white fixed">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 w-screen h-14 bg-slate-600">
                <div class="mt-2 ml-6 text-2xl" style="font-family: Ubunto;">Logo</div>
                <nav class="flex justify-end ">
                    <a href="#" class="menu-open-btn absolute mt-3 mr-7">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fo-color fa-xl"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div
                        class="w-1/3 main-menu duration-300 h-screen bg-slate-600 fixed flex items-center top-0 right-0">
                        <a href="#" class="menu-close-btn absolute top-4 left-5">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-x fa-xl fo-color"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="">
                            <li class="hover:text-lime-600 duration-200 ml-5">Home</li>
                            <li class="hover:text-lime-600 duration-200 ml-5">About Us</li>
                            <li class="hover:text-lime-600 duration-200 ml-5">Contact</li>
                            <li class="hover:text-lime-600 duration-200 ml-5">Team</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="overflow-hidden">
            <div class="">
                <img src="./img/businesspeople.avif" alt="photo" class="h-auto w-screen bg-indigo-500 opacity-50">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        let main_menu = document.querySelector(".main-menu")
        let menu_open_btn = document.querySelector(".menu-open-btn")
        let menu_close_btn = document.querySelector(".menu-close-btn")

        menu_open_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            main_menu.classList.remove("translate-x-full")
            main_menu.classList.add("translate-x-0")
        })

        menu_close_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            main_menu.classList.remove("translate-x-0")
            main_menu.classList.add("translate-x-full")
        })
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have only one `img` tag that looks fine but as I use opacity it effects everything and stops them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because using opacity with a value less than 1 places the element in a new stacking context. One way to fix it is to adjust the z-index by adding a negative z index such as `-z-10 relative` on the image. (Side note: The `overflow-hidden` on the image container is not hiding any part of the image if that is what it's meant to do.)

```html
<img src="./img/businesspeople.avif" 
  alt="photo" class="h-auto w-screen bg-indigo-500 opacity-50 
  -z-10 relative">
```

---

#### Detailed explanation

The reason why the image is behind everything originally is because within the same stacking context (and the only one in your case), non-positioned elements will appear behind `z-index:auto` positioned elements (anything that is not `position:static`.)

Since the image and its container div are both `position:static` which are non-positioned, while the whole `header` is set to `position:fixed`, the image will be drawn behind the header.

However, if you set opacity to less than 1 on a non-positioned element, it will be painted on the same layer, within its parent stacking context, **as positioned elements with stack level 0**. Now, since the header and the image are both seen as positioned element without positive stack level in the same stacking context, the later appeared in the DOM (which is the image) will be drawn in the front.

In W3C Spec [3.2. Transparency: the ‘opacity’ property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#transparency):

> If an element with opacity less than 1 is not positioned, then it is painted on the same layer, within its parent stacking context, as positioned elements with stack level 0.